# htaccess-redirect based on logged user

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, redirect

I have problem with password/user checking with redirect to user folder.
This is my .htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter the password to gain access."
AuthUserFile /home/path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) http://anothersite/clientarea/%1/$1 [L]
```

Problem:

- Serwer always redirect to http://anothersite/clientarea/user/ - even when the user is not entered into '.htpasswd' or when I enter wrong password

Comment: You may be seeing a browser caching issue. Test it in a different browser, or open a private/incognito session to test it with a new login.  Browsers aggressively cache redirects.  You might also use `[L,R=302]` to inform the browser that it is a temporary redirect so it won't cache it.

Comment: It's not caching issue - checked.
Change from `[L]` to `[L,R=302]` nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/clientarea/user
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} user(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /clientarea/user%1/$1 [L]
```

Where is your .htaccess file? It should be in user directory which you authenticate.

Comment: Redirect in .htaccess work fine, but checking loged user not working.. even user is not exist..
- when I enter 'pupa' as login browser go to http://anothersite/clientarea/pupa - but user 'pupa' not exist in .htpasswd
- when I enter good user with wrong password system still redirect, but should ask again for password